# How to remove an entire row if one column is empty

Tags: sql

Say I have the following table:

```
Tree     Park      Slide       
1           1        1
1           1        1
                     1
1                    1
```

What kind of code would I use to remove the rows that have empty columns such that I would just have the following result

```
 Tree     Park      Slide       
    1           1        1
    1           1        1
```

I am new to sql and was wondering on some tips on how to write this code. Would I use a case statement such that

```
Case
WHEN Tree IS NULL OR Park IS NULL
--Then what would I say to remove the row
```

Comment: by removing the row you mean deleting it from the db or unselecting it with your sql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DELETE` to delete a row and check it with `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE Tree IS NULL OR Park IS NULL OR Slide IS NULL
```

If you also want to delete rows where one of these columns is not null but empty text(if it's a `varchar` column):

```
DELETE FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE (Tree IS NULL OR Tree = '') 
 OR   (Park IS NULL OR Park = '') 
 OR   (Slide IS NULL OR Slide = '')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *physically deleting* then just put that in your `WHERE`:

```
DELETE FROM {table}
WHERE Tree IS NULL 
   OR Park IS NULL
   OR Slide IS NULL
```

Or take advantage of the fact that `{null} + n = {null}` and just do:

```
DELETE FROM {table}
WHERE (Tree+Park+Slide) IS NULL
```

But I would *definitely* add a comment to explain *why* that works.

If you mean *excluding from `SELECT` results* then you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM {table}
WHERE Tree IS NOT NULL 
  AND Park IS NOT NULL
  AND Slide IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Could you also say `SELECT * from {table} where (Tree+Park+Slide) IS NOT NULL`...If so, wonder which would be faster?

Comment: @PermaNoob certainly - without indexes it is a table scan either way. with an index on `Tree+Park+Slide` it would probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

No case statement required, just a where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Tree IS NOT NULL
AND Park IS NOT NULL
AND Slide IS NOT NULL
```

---

Note - reading the comments - this does not delete from the DB, just filters the output of a select.  Tim Schmelter's answer would be correct for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE Tree IS NULL or Park IS NULL or Slide IS NULL` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a `delete` like this:-

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE Tree IS NULL 
   OR Park IS NULL
   OR Slide IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE (Tree+Park) IS NULL
```

This is because

> NULL+NonNullValue = NULL

and

> NULL+NULL=NULL

(obviously)

Simpler way would be:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE Tree is NULL OR Park is NULL
```